# How to update client labels from a server in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, client-server, auto-update

I have a client that refreshes with the server every 10 seconds. When the client checks in with the server. I would like the server to send label text values back to the client to be applied to client labels.

The client sends a serial key and once the server verifies it. the server sends back a message to the client. I have a itemPrice to be used as a label text being sent in that same action before the connection breaks. I have no idea how to retrieve the itemPrice on the client side. Is there a way of tagging the value to be used for a client variable?

The server will be holding the text for client labels. How can i send this text to be a variable on the client?

Client.py

```
from tkinter import *
import socket


root = Tk()
# Variables
itemPrice1 = ''
itemPrice2 = ''


# SERVER CONNECTION
serialNumber = '001'

# Define Refresh Time
def Refresh():
    root.after(10000, Refresh)  # every 10 seconds...
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
    sock.connect(server_address)
    sock.send(serialNumber.encode('UTF-8'))
    amount_received = 0
    data = sock.recv(16)
    amount_received += len(data)
    print('received "%s"' % data)

# Layout
root.config(background='black')
item1 = Label(root, text=itemPrice1)
item1.grid(row=0, column=0)
item1.config(background='grey', width=10)
closeButton = Button(root, text='Close', command=root.destroy)
closeButton.grid(row=1, column=0)


Refresh()
root.mainloop()
```

Server.py

```
import socket
import data
import price

# VARIABLES
itemPrice1 = price.itemPrice1

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
print('starting up on %s port %s' % server_address)
sock.bind(server_address)

# Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    # Wait for a connection
    print('waiting for a connection')
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        print('connection from', client_address)

        # Receive the data in small chunks and retransmit it
        while True:
            dataRec = connection.recv(16)
            print(client_address, dataRec)
            if dataRec == data.serialNumber:
                print('sending data back to the client')
                connection.send('Serial Valid'.encode('UTF-8'))
                connection.send(itemPrice1)

                break
            else:
                connection.send('Key Not Valid'.encode('UTF-8'))
                break

    finally:
        # Clean up the connection
        connection.close()
```

Price.py

```
itemPrice1 = b'0.01'
```

Data.py

```
serialNumber = b'001'
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and explain ***"Is there a way of tagging the value to be used for a client variable?*"*** more detaild. Give an example what you expect to receive?

Comment: Read about [module-json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json)

Comment: would the server be able to send a json file to the client? or would that require another application to do that?

Comment: ***"server be able to send a json"***: `json` module is standard `python`, not other module/app requiered, so **Yes**

Answer (score 0):

For the server. I removed the variables and forward the prices directly from the price.py

```
            if dataRec == data.serialNumber:
                print('sending data back to the client')
                connection.send('Serial Valid'.encode('UTF-8'))
                connection.send(price.itemPrice1.encode('UTF-8'))  # SENDING PRICE TO CLIENT FOR LABEL
                connection.send(price.itemPrice2.encode('UTF-8'))
                break
```

For the client. I placed the variables directly in the definition.

```
def Refresh():
    root.after(10000, Refresh)  # every 10 seconds...
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
    sock.connect(server_address)
    sock.send(serialNumber.encode('UTF-8'))
    amount_received = 0
    data = sock.recv(12)
    amount_received += len(data)
    print('received "%s"' % data)
    itemPrice1 = sock.recv(4)
    print('price', itemPrice1)
    itemPrice1Label.config(text=itemPrice1)
    itemPrice2 = sock.recv(4)
    print('price', itemPrice2)
    itemPrice2Label.config(text=itemPrice2)
```

Doing this I have to define the sock.recv() amount so the character count doesn't overlap with each other. Example being.

```
item price 1 = 1.05
item price 2 = 0.10

itemPrice1 = sock.recv(7)
would print 1.050.1
vs
itemPrice1 = sock.recv(4)
would print 1.05
```